# How to generate a regular panel from an irregular panel time series data

Tags: r, time-series, panel

I would like to go from an irregular panel data structure to a regular panel data structure, but I am struggling how to do it. Any suggestions welcome!

Current irregular panel data structure:

```
trackingid <- as.character(c(1470149111625446735))
timestamp <- as.character(c("2018-06-17", "2018-06-18", "2018-06-19", "2018-06-21", "2018-06-22", "2018-06-23"))
pageimp <- as.numeric(c(8, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3))
dt <- data.frame(trackingid,timestamp, pageimp)
```

Aspired regular panel data structure:

```
trackingid <- as.character(c(1470149111625446735))
timestamp <- as.character(c("2018-06-17", "2018-06-18", "2018-06-19", "2018-06-20", "2018-06-21", "2018-06-22", "2018-06-23"))
pageimp <- as.numeric(c(8, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2, 3))
dt <- data.frame(trackingid,timestamp, pageimp)
```

Note in my full data, I will have many more trackingids with varying irregular time-stamps. All prior solutions so far discussed only moving from an irregular time series to a regular time series not considering the panel nature of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  mutate(timestamp = as.Date(timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(trackingid) %>%
  complete(timestamp = seq(min(timestamp), max(timestamp), by = "day"), fill = list(pageimp = 0))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   trackingid [1]
  trackingid          timestamp  pageimp
  <fct>               <date>       <dbl>
1 1470149111625446656 2018-06-17       8
2 1470149111625446656 2018-06-18       1
3 1470149111625446656 2018-06-19       3
4 1470149111625446656 2018-06-20       0
5 1470149111625446656 2018-06-21       4
6 1470149111625446656 2018-06-22       2
7 1470149111625446656 2018-06-23       3
```

Basically you group by `trackingid`, expand your data by day from the minimum to maximum `timestamp`, and make use of `fill` argument to populate anything missing with 0.

Comment: Thanks arg0naut this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting and/or upvoting if it helped.